# How can get past 5 edits

Tags: support, editing

Sometimes, I need to edit multiple answers, (updates, changes, new ways, etc.).  But I found out that I could only do 5 edits per day.

How can get past this:

> You have already edited 5 of your own posts today (excluding very
>   recent posts); further edits are not allowed until tomorrow.

Instead of waiting till tomorrow?

Answer (score 2):

It is a feature of the system that you can't edit your own posts more than five times. You should try to consolidate multiple edits made to one post into one, and use comments for small communications, not edits. Disclaimer: I am ***NOT*** a moderator, so I cannot be sure of the exact rule.

Actually, this appears to make it so you can't keep bumping your questions on the homepage, whether to get votes, or to draw unfair attention for an answer. Either way, it is useful IMO and will remain that way for the foreseeable future.

Even if you hit 5 edits on your posts, you can edit others' posts at your will.

Comment: I don't want to edit my own posts more than five times.  I want to be able to edit more that five posts.:)

Comment: I've edited more than five posts before :P.  The issue is you're editing *your own* posts, that's what the error says (other than very recent posts)

Comment: I've seen one post with 42 edits made by the author, and there may be other posts out there that have even more edits made by the same person than that.